PCA and tICA on autocorrelated and/or non-equilibrium data
As you can infer from the title, what if I want to do a PCA or a time-lagged Independent Component Analysis of a process where each of the features I consider are sampled in points that, per each or some of the features, are autocorrelated (i.e. carry the memory of their precedent state)? I should not consider them random, so what about the meaning of the result in case of each mentioned algorithm?
Then, suppose I have another scenario I do sample the points with sufficient time-spacing between the series, but I sample a process which is still evolving towards the equilibrium. What is the meaning of each of the two results with these algorithms?
Finally, as a separated question I would like to know whether both randomicity and stationary process need to be satisfied to apply the two techniques.
